# Race-condition creating folder in Python

Tags: python, caching, race-condition

I have a urllib2 caching module, which sporadically crashes because of the following code:

```
if not os.path.exists(self.cache_location):
    os.mkdir(self.cache_location)
```

The problem is, by the time the second line is being executed, the folder may exist, and will error:

```
  File ".../cache.py", line 103, in __init__
    os.mkdir(self.cache_location)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/tmp/examplecachedir/'
```

This is because the script is simultaneously launched numerous times, by third-party code I have no control over.

The code (before I attempted to fix the bug) can be found [here, on github](http://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api/commit/e7429cce89fb2406efce6d81336e2ffa01479976)

I can't use the [tempfile.mkstemp](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp), as it solves the race condition by using a randomly named directory ([tempfile.py source here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/tempfile.py)), which would defeat the purpose of the cache.

I don't want to simply discard the error, as the same error Errno 17 error is raised if the folder name exists as a file (a different error), for example:

```
$ touch blah
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir("blah")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'blah'
>>>
```

I cannot using `threading.RLock` as the code is called from multiple processes.

So, I tried writing a simple file-based lock ([that version can be found here](http://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api/blob/343df228d519ac5c8895a1e6bdab8d259a64cdb9/cache.py)), but this has a problem: it creates the lockfile one level up, so `/tmp/example.lock` for `/tmp/example/`, which breaks if you use `/tmp/` as a cache dir (as it tries to make `/tmp.lock`)..

In short, I need to cache `urllib2` responses to disc. To do this, I need to access a known directory (creating it, if required), in a multiprocess safe way. It needs to work on OS X, Linux and Windows.

Thoughts? The only alternative solution I can think of is to rewrite the cache module using SQLite3 storage, rather than files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3.x, you can use `os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)`, which will not raise any exception if such directory exists. It will raise `FileExistsError: [Errno 17]` if a file exists with the same name as the requested directory (`path`).

Verify it with:

```
import os

parent = os.path.dirname(__file__)

target = os.path.join(parent, 'target')

os.makedirs(target, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(target, exist_ok=True)

os.rmdir(target)

with open(target, 'w'):
    pass

os.makedirs(target, exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 11):

Instead of

```
if not os.path.exists(self.cache_location):
    os.mkdir(self.cache_location)
```

you could do

```
try:
    os.makedirs(self.cache_location)
except OSError:
    pass
```

As you would end up with the same *functionality*.

<sub>DISCLAIMER: I don't know how Pythonic this might be.</sub>

---

Using `SQLite3`, *might* be a bit of overkill, but would add a *lot* of functionality and flexibility to your use case.

If you have to do a lot of "selecting", concurrent inserting and filtering, it's a great idea to use `SQLite3`, as it wont add too much complexity over simple files (it could be argued that it removes complexity).

---

Rereading your question (and comments) I can better understand your problem.

What is the possibility that a **file** could create the same race condition?

If it is small enough, then I'd do something like:

```
if not os.path.isfile(self.cache_location):
    try:
        os.makedirs(self.cache_location)
    except OSError:
        pass
```

Also, reading your code, I'd change

```
else:
    # Our target dir is already a file, or different error,
    # relay the error!
    raise OSError(e)
```

to

```
else:
    # Our target dir is already a file, or different error,
    # relay the error!
    raise
```

as it's really what you want, Python to reraise the exact same exception <sub>(just nitpicking)</sub>.

---

One more thing, may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474052/synchronize-shell-script-execution) could be of use for you (Unix-like only).

Comment: Agreed, though you might consider using `os.makedirs` instead, which create parent directories as well, if necessary.

Comment: For many cases, ignoring the error would be Pythonic, but in this case it could cause other problems, as I addressed in the question - "I don't want to simply discard the error, as the same error Errno 17 error is raised if the folder name exists as a file (a different error)" - discarding the exception would mean the temp directory either doesn't exist (say, a permission denied error), or is a useless file (and would cause errors further down the path)

Comment: Also, I agree with your points about SQLite - I wouldn't have to do much in the way of filtering (pretty much just "has this URL been requested in the last x hours"), but SQLite would remove a lot of the complexity (no constructing cached-file paths and checking file modification times), and I think it should deal with all the locking issues (both for specific bits of cached data, and the sqlite file itself).. Hm... If Pythonic Metaphor's solution doesn't work, I may start this (in fact I may regardless, a nice SQLite backed urllib2 cache module would be useful)

Comment: @dbr: If you want to distinguish between "directory already exists as directory" and "directory name already exists as file", you do that in the except clause.  Don't make this too complex.  Simply handle the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Catching OSError, checking if the dir exists and if so ignoring the error seems to work fine, and will still correctly error if the user has insufficient permissions. I've made the change you suggested to the code, I completely forgot `raise` will re-raise the caught exception.

Answer (score 10):

The code I ended up with was:

```
import os
import errno

folder_location = "/tmp/example_dir"

try:
    os.mkdir(folder_location)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(folder_location):
        # File exists, and it's a directory,
        # another process beat us to creating this dir, that's OK.
        pass
    else:
        # Our target dir exists as a file, or different error,
        # reraise the error!
        raise
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you catch the exception and then test whether the file exists as a directory or not?

Comment: Possibly! I thought of that just as I was re-reading the question, before submitting it.. I've implemented this ( http://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api/blob/468d9f816373b14ef3a483fca07e031b69fa62f9/cache.py#L103-114 ), and will get the person who reported the bug to test it shortly.

Comment: @dbr: note that on line 114, you want `raise e` since it's already an instance of `OSError` . http://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api/blob/468d9f816373b14ef3a483fca07e031b69fa62f9/cache.py#L114

Answer (score 1):

When you have race conditions often EAFP(easier to ask forgiveness than permission) works better that LBYL(look before you leap)

[Error checking strategies](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0596001886/pythonian-CHP-6-SECT-6)

Comment: This all depends on likelihood of conflicts - EAFP = optimistic concurrency, which checks for conflict after trying the operation, and works well if there is small probability of conflicts.  LBYL = pessimistic concurrency which checks before operation and is better if there are many conflicts typically.  For a simple case like this I think pessimistic is better.

Comment: @RichVel, with LBYL here you have the possibility of a race condition. So you need extra code to handle the exception anyway. So it's only a simple operation and the extra code isn't much now, but these things have a way of growing over the life of the project. There is an extra cost every time someone needs to read/understand/debug this extra code. I think it's likely to be a premature and unnecessary optimisation in this case.

Comment: That's not the case, because mkdir is atomic i.e. it is equivalent to a single 'test-and-set' operation.  Coding LBYL operations with non-atomic test and set operations will cause race conditions, but that's an implementation error.