# Is os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True) susceptible to race-conditions?

Tags: python

Suppose two different processes simultaneously call `os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)`. Is it possible that one will raise a spurious exception due to a race condition?

My fear is the call might do something like this under the hood:

```
if not dir_exists(d):
    try_make_dir_and_raise_if_exists(d)
```

I carefully read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs), but I see no clear assertion of race-condition safety.

Some other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57394882/543913) on this site suggest the call is safe, but provide no citations.

Comment: It's unclear why it matters.  With the `exist_ok` set to True, one of them will fail to make the directory as it exists but will silently continue on.  If it wasn't True then one would get an exception.  What is it you're trying to prove to yourself?

Comment: @stdunbar OP is afraid that if the implementation prevents an exception with a look-before-you-leap implementation, then it may in fact raise an error in race conditions.

Comment: If you haven't demonstrated that a problem exists, do you really have a "specific problem you actually face" as our rules require?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Are you suggesting that if you have a suspected race-condition possibility in your code, that it is not appropriate to ask questions about it until you actually encounter the race-condition?

Comment: @dshin, I'm suggesting that there should be some _actual cause_ to believe there's a race condition before asking about it. If you haven't even read the implementation, much less done analysis to lead you to believe that that implementation is suspect, surely there's not enough diligence done to have a good-faith belief that there's likely to be a real problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's unclear to me, when dealing with possibly rare race conditions, where to draw the line between "actual cause" / "good-faith belief" vs not. I tend to try to reason fully about such cases before any empirical evidence appears. In this case, looking at the implementation obviously helps, but I hope you can understand that doing so is not a first instinct for someone that has never done that before for a core-library module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8da83f3386da603605358dc9ec68796daa5ef455/Lib/os.py#L202):

```py
try:
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
except FileExistsError:
    # Defeats race condition when another thread created the path
    pass
```

So no exception in case of someone else creating the same path.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the FileExistsError could come from *mkdir()* which is the underlying mechanism for creating the directories

Comment: When `mkdir` raises an exception, it might be `FileExistsError`, which `exists_ok=True` suppresses, or it might be some *other* `OSError` which `exists_ok=True` must *not* suppress. Here, you only point out that `exist_ok` is passed on to the recursive call to `makedirs` *regardless* of its value.

Comment: @CtrlZ That's the *only* place it can come from, ultimately. `makdirs` itself does not explicitly raise any exception.